# “Your Apple ID has been disabled”

Tags: iphone, apple-id

My friend has an iPhone 6S+ and he can’t install or update any apps or music etc. he gets the message in the title. How can this be fixed?

Comment: The top hit searching Google for "how to fix your Apple ID has been disabled" was: [If your Apple ID is locked or disabled](https://support.apple.com/HT204106)

Answer (score 5):

[Source](https://appletoolbox.com/2015/12/how-to-fix-your-disabled-apple-id/):

Most likely, your friend typed in the wrong password more than 3 times.  When this happens, Apple automatically disables the ID for security reasons.

To fix it, do the following:

1. Using a desktop device, go to [I forgot my Apple ID](https://iforgot.apple.com/appleid#!&section=appleid).[image]
2. Fill-in your details and click **Continue**.
3. Choose how to reset your password using one of these four methods:

   - Select Answer security questions and follow the steps
   - Tap Get an email to reset your password. Email is sent to your primary (or rescue) email address (steps listed directly below)
   - When you enable two-factor authentication for your Apple ID, resetting your password is easy using any of your trusted devices. Skip to Two-Factor Verification
   - If you have two-step verification on, Apple asks for a Recovery Key, follow the steps for two-step verification instead. Skip to Two-Step Verification.
     [image]
4. If you don’t use the two steps verification method, you will have to go your Email account and check for the recent email from the Apple. In your Email, Click on the **Reset Now**.
5. Write down the new password and click on **Reset Password**.

Apple will reset your password.  Here's what the screen could look like:
[image]

Comment: I called Apple support and this wasn’t the case but the situation has been resolved.

Comment: Based on the info you provided in your question, this was the most-likely resolution.  Perhaps you can add an answer with the details of what fixed the problem?  This will help others who have a similar situation.

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what the issue was but after calling Apple support I explained what I thought might be the cause but they assured me that it was something other than what I thought and what was listed here. Unfortunately I didn’t ask exactly what was wrong.